# how to prepend div while scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make same demo as we do in lazy loading or pull to refresh .I don't want to use iscroll .I want to prepend some text when user goes to top of div .That text also scroll to exiting div .If whole text now scroll to top of content again it will prepend the text of that  content.
My problem is that when I prepend the text it will not scroll with existing text or data and there is some gap in between the data .

can we achieve that thing same as lazy loading.I don't want to prepend to same div because I want to remove that text (prepend text when user goes bottom of the div).
http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/19/

```
$("#contend").scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() === 0){
        alert("ss");
        $("#pre").prepend(" Distinguished service of a high degree to Australia or to humanity at largefjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf ");
    }
});

$("#contend").scroll(function() {
    if ($('#contend').scrollTop() >= $('#contend')[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) { 
        $("#pre").html('');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/20/ ..please check I will get some success.But not it will stop appending

Answer (score 0):

Still the question bit confusing, but as far as I understand, how about `position:absolute;`

**JS**

```
$("#contend").scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        alert("ss");
        $("#pre").html($("#pre").html() + " Distinguished service of a high degree to Australia or to humanity at largefjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf ");
        $(this).css('padding-top', $("#pre").height());
    }
});

$("#contend").scroll(function () {
    if ($('#contend').scrollTop() >= $('#contend')[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) {
        $("#pre").html('');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    position:relative;
}
#contend {
    height:200px;
    background:#f00;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#pre {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#black;
    overflow:quto;
}
```

**HTML structure**

```
<div id='wrap'>
    <div id="pre"></div>
    <div id="contend"> contents...</div>
</div>
```

updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/24/)

Comment: I want to preappend the text again and again

Comment: please check my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/19/ .it is preappend text whenever user goes to top of the line

Comment: @user1542984 Ok, got it. Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/24/)

Comment: First : height is increasing when text is preappend

Comment: Second :You will See there is overide text on screen .

Comment: Third :the focus will goes to top of line when the text is preappend it should remain on same line where it is preappend

Comment: What do you mean by height increasing? Could you please be a bit more elaborative on the issue, update it accordingly?

Comment: contend height is  height:200px; when it preappend data it height increase.Actually I need height should be 200 PX fixed data should scroll

Comment: When The user append focus should remain on last focus (mean that line where it is preappend)